# how can I measure the radius of a circle inside a triangle in cm?

Tags: triangles, circles

I am trying to calculate the radius of circle inside a triangle in cm.
I am given this info:
We have a side that is 12cm and the angle infront of it is 30 degrees, the wanted result is the radius(R) in cm.
This is what is the image I created based of the information we have

[image]

Comment: Is it a right triangle?

Comment: **Hint :** each side of the triangle is tangential to the circle, hence it is perpendicular to the radius joining the center of the circle to the tangential point.

Comment: @Vasya it doesn't actually says what triangle we have, I just know that one of the sides is 12cm and the angle against it is 30 degrees, no other parameters

Comment: Any additional info about the problem? It's not possible to solve with the given info (there are infinitely many triangles with these two parameters).

Comment: Whoever wrote the question probably just forgot to draw in the right angle...

Comment: Maybe, author needs to find not inscribed circle radius, but circumscribed? Then angle and opposite side length will be enough data.

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches...

Plot the triangle on the coordinate plane with the right angle on the origin and the legs on the axes.  Find equations for the lines that are angle bisectors.  Find the point of intersection.  Find the distance to  one of the legs.

Method 2:

Construct the radii to the points of tangency.  This will create several congruent triangles.

The side lengths of the triangle will be $a+b, a+c,$ and $b+c$.  Since this is a right triangle one of $a,b,c$ will equal the radius.

Method 3:

The law of cotangents says the perimeter times the radius is half the area.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you first have to find all the sides of the triangle using trigonometry. Then you name the shortest side of the triangle '$a$' the hypotenuse '$c$' and the middle side length as '$b$'. then you can just put the values in the general formula for the radius of incircle of a right triangle $2R=a+b-c$ and just find the value of $R$ and by default, you will get the values in cm.

Comment: pot the values?

Comment: what do you mean by "pot the values ?".Come again pls I didn't get you.